# Does @ddt work with py.test?

Tags: python, selenium, pytest, ddt

Does @ddt work with py.test or it must use unittest format?
I have a tests where the setup fixture is in the conftest.py file. When I run the test, it error out because it didn't run the setup fixture. E.g:

```
@ddt
class Test_searchProd:
  @data(['clothes': 3],['shoes': 4])
  @unpack
  def test_searchAllProduct(setup,productType):
      .....
```

Basically the setup fixture is to open a specific URL...
Am I doing something incorrect or @ddt does not work with py.test?

Answer (score 10):

[ddt](http://ddt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is meant to be used by `TestCase` subclasses, so it won't work for bare test classes. But note that pytest can run `TestCase` subclasses which use `ddt` just fine, so if you already have a ddt-based test suite it should run without modifications using the pytest runner.

Also note that pytest has [parametrize](http://pytest.org/latest/parametrize.html), which can be used to replace many use cases supported by `ddt`.

For example, the following ddt-based tests:

```
@ddt
class FooTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    @data(1, -3, 2, 0)
    def test_not_larger_than_two(self, value):
        self.assertFalse(larger_than_two(value))

    @data(annotated(2, 1), annotated(10, 5))
    def test_greater(self, value):
        a, b = value
        self.assertGreater(a, b)
```

Become in pytest:

```
class FooTest:

    @pytest.mark.parametrize('value', (1, -3, 2, 0))
    def test_not_larger_than_two(self, value):
        assert not larger_than_two(value)

    @pytest.mark.parametrize('a, b', [(2, 1), (10, 5)])
    def test_greater(self, a, b):
        assert a > b
```

Or you can even get rid of the class altogether if you prefer:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('value', (1, -3, 2, 0))
def test_not_larger_than_two(value):
    assert not larger_than_two(value)

@pytest.mark.parametrize('a, b', [(2, 1), (10, 5)])
def test_greater(a, b):
    assert a > b
```

Comment: Brilliant! Totally forgot about the parametrize functionality. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't even know about it, thank you from releasing me from the shackles of ddt.