# pytest, Test Case is throwing fixture 'sort_by' not found when we try to pass test data using ddt

Tags: python, pytest, ddt

Executed the following code in Pycharm

```
from ddt import file_data, ddt
import pytest

@ddt
class TestCase:
    @file_data('../testdata/testdatajson.json')
    def test_ddtfile(self, sort_by, sort_id):
        print(sort_by, sort_id)
```

Test Data file:

```
{
  "test1" : {
    "sort_by": 2,
    "sort_id" : "wc-block-components-sort-select__select-0"
  }
}
```

I am getting below error

```
________________________________________________________ ERROR at setup of TestCase.test_ddtfile_1_test1 _________________________________________________________
file D:\WORK_WK\learn_github\testcases\test_ddtfile.py, line 6
      @file_data('../testdata/testdatajson.json')
      def test_ddtfile(self, sort_by, sort_id):
E       fixture 'sort_by' not found
>       available fixtures: GSSetup, cache, capfd, capfdbinary, caplog, capsys, capsysbinary, doctest_namespace, monkeypatch, pytestconfig, record_property, record
_testsuite_property, record_xml_attribute, recwarn, tmp_path, tmp_path_factory, tmpdir, tmpdir_factory
>       use 'pytest --fixtures [testpath]' for help on them.
```

Can anyone please provide solution?

Comment: sort_by and sort_id are fixtures they need to be defined somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that DDT is meant to be used with unittest, not pytest.
[This question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29836946/does-ddt-work-with-py-test) does a good job explaining the problem and offering some solutions.

I'll also add that I wrote a pytest plugin called [Parametrize From File](https://parametrize-from-file.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that fills a similar niche as DDT.  Here's how it would look for your example:

Test script:

```py
import parametrize_from_file

@parametrize_from_file
def test_sort(sort_by, sort_id):
    print(sort_by, sort_id)
```

Test data:

```json
{
  "test_sort": [
    {
      "sort_by": 2,
      "sort_id" : "wc-block-components-sort-select__select-0"
    }
  ]
}
```

Note that the JSON file has a slightly different structure than before.  You could use the original file if you wanted to, but you'd have to provide a few extra arguments to the `@parametrize_from_file` decorator.